# Stuttery performance issues with Jquery Mobile and Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

So, I am developing an app using phonegap and jqm. Everything works great and it's all pretty easy thanks to phonegap build. However, I've started to see some 'stutter issues' that are really annoying. My app at the moment only has two pages and the transition effect between them is 'slide'. The first page has a background color set to it and the second one does not. Some of the issues:

1. When I navigate from page 1 to page 2, half of the page has the background color from the previous page. It goes away after I do some random swipes on screen.
2. On one of the pages, I have a regular form with some text input fields and a radio button set at the end. When I move from an input box to the radio button the keyboard slides down but it is replaced by a black area for a short period of time.
3. The fixed header that I have at the top randomly decides to disappear and reappear again.

These are only few of the annoying ones and these only happen on the mobile device and it works fine on the computer. So, I know it's a performance issue.

I've read up about this on the internet and here on SO and different solution have been proposed like writing custom CSS3 transitions (to take advantage of hardware acceleration) or using something like zepto.js.

What in your opinion would be the best 'cross device compatible' method to overcome these? Is there a way to force hardware acceleration with jquery mobile? Is CSS3 performance even across device platforms?

**PS.** I have been testing on jelly bean 4.2.2. I am not posting any of my code because they are just plain form elements and some input tags and this happens on multiple pages which are totally different so I am pretty sure this isn't code related.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Jquery Mobile is using CSS3 transitions.

Comment: Wrong thread title. I was about to tell you that you can't whine for performance when using jQuery, but then I saw it was just visual glitches. Might want to fill a bug ticket at jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery writes animations using Javascript which dynamically writes inline styles that change quickly. The issue with that, is that it isn't using the hardware acceleration and if you are testing on a retina device, it animates using pixels as they are a unit of measurement. So it is skipping half of your pixels which causes the stutter.

I have written apps using PhoneGap and the best way I came up was to use CSS3 animations/transitions. Super smooth and they feel just like a native app. You will still use JQuery to add/remove classes, etc., but the movement should come from your CSS.